# weex can't install plugin

Tags: plugins, installation, addition, weex

I run this command

```
weex platform add ios
```

Then added a plugin using command

```
weex plugin add weex-svg
```

Always encouter this error

```
Error: The provided path "/Users/rupert/Code/test/svgapp/platforms/ios/Weexplugin" is not a weexpack iOS project.
```

Why am I getting this Error, and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think weex-svg is more maintainable to support newer weex enviroment. I have removed svg and started using images. Hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

```
ca /Users/rupert/Code/test/svgapp && weex plugin add weex-svg
```

Comment: Some description will be helpful, Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)